# Lua C API: Stack empty after pcall error

Tags: c, lua

I have a problem using Lua C API. When pcall (C API function) fail, the error is pushed on the stack.
`lua_tostring` shows an error on the stack but `lua_gettop` shows says the stack is empty.

```
#include <lua5.2/lauxlib.h>
#include <lua5.2/lua.h>
#include <lua5.2/lualib.h>

int main()
{
    lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
    lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0);
    printf("%d\n", lua_gettop(L)); // outputs 0, indicating empty stack
    printf("%s\n", lua_tostring(L, -1)); // outputs "attempt to call a nil value", indicating non-empty stack
}
```

Compile with: gcc main.c `pkg-config --cflags lua5.2` `pkg-config --libs lua5.2`

This program display:
    0
    attempt to call a nil value

lua_gettop(L) return the stack size. Here I get 0. How can I get a string from an empty stack ?

The behavior is the same with the 5.1 version.

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered in the Lua mailing list. The behavior is correct: you need to push a function onto the stack to call it. The stack after `luaL_newstate` is empty.

*Edit:*
The OP said "How can I get a string from an empty stack?". My answer is: Why do you want to get something from an empty stack, when you *know* it is empty since `lua_gettop` returned 0?

Bottom line:

- The stack was empty before calling `lua_pcall`. This is an error. Lua recovered, but you can't count on it.
- The stack was empty after `lua_pcall`. Lua thinks so and tells you so via `lua_gettop`.
- You should not try to get a value from an empty stack. The string that is printed is just garbage left over by `lua_pcall`, but you can't count on it.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. He *knows* that the stack is empty after `luaL_newstate`, and he *knows* that you need to push a function on the stack to call it; he's forcing pcall to generate an error quite deliberately. The question is why is the stack top still 0 after pcall *has pushed an error message onto it*? His output shows that there *is* an error message on the stack ("attempt to call a nil value") yet `lua_gettop` returns 0, which according to the manual [indicates an *empty stack*](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#lua_gettop).

Comment: @Mud, the Lua API does not hold hands. If you give it garbage, you'll probably get garbage. `lua_pcall` assumes there is a function on the stack to be called.

Comment: Your edit says "How can I get a string from an empty stack?", but it's not empty: it has a string on it. `lua_tostring` proves it. I guess the answer is that calling `lua_pcall` without first pushing *something* onto the stack (even nil) is going to leave the stack in a garbage state, where it reports being empty when in fact it's not?

Comment: @Mud, the stack is empty because `lua_gettop` returned 0. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, lua_pcall does not push an error string. Instead, it overwrites the value at the top of the stack (since there should always **at least** be a function there ;p). Therefore, lua_pcall (or, more correctly, debug.traceback, I believe) blindly overwrites the top of the stack, not modifying the stack pointer.

Therefore, when lua_pcall returns, the value is at the top of the stack, but the stack pointer signifies that the stack is empty (as it was when you called lua_pcall).

I would assume this is a measure to avoid more serious errors (e.g. if there was memory corruption or an out of memory error, we wouldn't want to be allocating more stack space for the error message would we?).